# how can I style a specific ul without effecting other lists on webpage

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have various ul on my web page but since adding the latest one its styling is effecting the other lists on the page. How can i make sure the styling for this ul only effects this one. I have tried and tried but can not get it to work.

HTML CODE

CSS

```
.image{
height: 252px;
width: 252px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
background-image: url(../images/danmorris_profile.png);
}
.overlay{
width:252px;
height:252px;
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:40px;
left:0px;
}
.overlay div {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
top:40px;
margin: 40px 5px 0 0;
}

ul { list-style: none; width: 252px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 60px;

}

ul li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 252px;
height: 252px;
}

li:hover .overlay {
display:block;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.75;
}
.bt1 {
background-color:orange;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
.bt2 {
background-color:green;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give your `<ul>` tag a specific class or id and reference it by that: `<ul class="my_class">` and `ul.my_class  { ... }`

Comment: Brillant. That's what i was trying but i was doing it the opposite way round in css styling e.g .my_class ul - not sure why that makes such a difference but its working now. Thanks!

Comment: Well, css is a programming language. As such it has a very specific syntax. You cannot simply note down things "somehow along the line", or "a bit like this". you have to obey the syntax and definition. And the two notations you compare describe something totally different. 1. start reading a documentation of basic css usage and 2. start using your browsers development console to control the application of your notation. 3. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ul` in your css you can put `#your_ul_id` and make your ul have this id : `<ul id="your_ul_id">...</ul>`

Or you can use class if there is more than one list you want to apply style :

Css:

`ul.some_class{ ... }`

And in html:

```
            <ul class="some_class" ></ul>
            <ul class="some_class" ></ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what has been said before in the comments. Well copied.

Comment: It's a very simple answer already .. If you are angry beacause of it i can delete it for you...

Comment: I am not angry or anything, why should I be? I just pointed out that this does not offer any new information. It just copies what has been written before. So what is the point is posting this afterwards?

Comment: @arkascha If you object to someone having the same answer as your comment...leave your own answer.